# ReferenceError: noticication_id is not defined in firebase notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am not receiving notifications on android device. This error occurs in function log.

> ReferenceError: noticication_id is not defined
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:28:84)
>       at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
>       at /worker/worker.js:825:24
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

---

My code in Index.js file:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context) =>
{
 const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
 const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;


 console.log('We have a notification to send to :' , receiver_user_id);


 if (!data.after.val()) 
 {
  console.log('A notification has been deleted :' , notification_id);
  return null;
 }

 const sender_user_id = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${noticication_id}`).once('value');

 return sender_user_id.then(fromUserResult =>
  {
   const from_sender_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

   console.log('you have a notification :',sender_user_id);

   const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

   return userQuery.then(userResult =>
   {
    const senderUserName = userResult.val();

   });


    const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return DeviceToken.then(result => 
    {
     const token_id = result.val();

     const payload = 
     {
      notification:
      {
       from_sender_user_id : from_sender_user_id,
       title: "New Chat Request",
       body: `you have a new Chat Request from${senderUserName}`,
       icon: "default"
      }
     };

     return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
     .then(response => 
      {
       console.log('This was a notification feature.');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you investigate (have a look at the trace)? Are you also sure the error contains "noticication_id" or is this a typing error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const sender_user_id = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${noticication_id}`).once('value');
```

Into this:

```
const sender_user_id = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
```

You have a typo in the variable, inside `ref()`, it should be `notification_id` instead of `noticication_id`

Comment: thanks log error is removed but i still can't receive the device to device notification can you pleas help

Comment: @TayyabAliMughal That would be best asked as a separate question but make sure to check that your client is configured to [receive messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), not just send them.